# Changing a button depending on whether a user has liked a post or not

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am creating a social media website where users can like each others posts. So far, I have implemented most of this, however I am missing one vital part.

This is changing the text within a button, depending on if a user has liked a post or not.

The 'tuser' variable finds a user within the many to many field named 'likes' which is on the Post class. Depending on whether it exists or not.

I pass a variable through to my 'home' template, which then if it exists, display  certain text in a button.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Like', related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def summary_pretty(self):
        return self.summary[:50]

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

class Like(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def likepost(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
        user = request.user
        if post.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            tuser = post.likes.filter(id=user.id)
            post.likes.remove(user)
            if tuser:
                return redirect('home', {'tuser': tuser})
            else:
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            like = Like()
            like.post = post
            like.user = user
            like.status = False
            like.save()
            post.likes.add(user)
            return redirect('home')
```

template code:

```
{% if tuser %}
         <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('likepost{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Unlike {{ post.total_likes }} </button></a>
{% else %}
         <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('likepost{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Like {{ post.total_likes }} </button></a>
{% endif %}
<form id="likepost{{ post.id }}" method="POST" action="{% url 'likepost' post.id %}">
  {% csrf_token%}
  <input type="hidden">
</form>
```

code that renders the home page:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'posts/home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where in your view function you render that template. All the `return`s I can see use `redirect`, not `render_template`. I'm assuming you've missed off the `GET` case? I also am not sure why in your models you have both a "likes" `ManyToManyField` linking `Post` to `User`, and a `Like` model with foreign keys to both. Either of these on its own would create the relationships you need, you neither need nor want both.

Comment: @RobinZigmond OP is using a "through" model on the ManyToMany with an additional field (`status`) which is a perfectly valid use case for having a separate model. But @djangoninja: `post.likes.add(user)` cannot be right, you've already created the relationship with `like.save()`, this line should throw an error, you cannot add a relationship like this in a "through" relationship.

Comment: What is the problem? You tell us what you want but you don't tell us what is the problem? What is the outcome of your code? What do you see that you don't want to see? An error?

Comment: @dirkgroten - oops, I didn't see the `through` kwarg, I'll delete that part of my comment [Actually I can't, it being more than 5 minutes old, so I guess I'll have to leave it as I think my other question is still very relevant.]

Comment: Hey @dirkgroten I have removed post.likes.add(user), however the functionality stays the same, and the button doesn't changed.

Comment: As Robin mentioned, you're not showing the code rendering the template.

Comment: Hey @dirkgroten I have edited my post and showed the code that renders the template.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have edited the original post and that shows the rendering code for the home page

Comment: @djangoninja is that really the same template that's rendered by that view? My main point of confusion is that you pass no `tuser` key in the context, which appears from the template to be the key to whatever is going wrong. (Also, if as it appears the homepage is rendering all posts - something which doesn't strike me as a good idea - surely you should be checking a property on the individual post objects, not a global one?)

Comment: as you can see there's no `tuser` in your context for the "home" view.

Comment: @dirkgroten Oh ok. When I do my redirect, I pass the tuser variable to my home view, which then I check exists within my home.html template.

Comment: you can't pass a variable like that to a redirect. Actually I'm surprised your redirect function doesn't throw an error, unless you have a url pattern that accepts `tuser` as a kwarg. When you redirect, your browser makes a **new request** entirely to your django app.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ah ok. How would you recommend implementing this functionality within my website.

Comment: In your home view you need to **annotate** each post in your query with whether or not the current user liked it. Look in the Django docs how to annotate queries.

Comment: @dirkgroten You mentioned 'each' post in my queries in the post view. How would I approach this using with the current query I am performing in my home view.